# The final local variable cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Tags: java, inner-classes, final

```
ratingS = new JSlider(1, 5, 3); 
ratingS.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
ratingS.setPaintLabels(true);
int vote;

class SliderMoved implements ChangeListener {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        vote = ratingS.getValue();
    }
}

ratingS.addChangeListener(new SliderMoved());
```

If i write the above code Eclipse tells me this:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable vote inside an inner class
>   defined in a different method

But if i add **final** before **int vote** it gives me this error:

> The final local variable vote cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

So, how to solve?

Comment: Try making it static or putting it in slidermoved but out of statechanged. Or access it as "this.vote" or "zxc myClass = new zxc(); and acces it as myClass.vote"

Comment: `vote` should be a field, not a local variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen?rq=1

Comment: I can't use "static"
**Illegal modifier for the variable vote; only final is permitted**
and other ways don't make my program work correctly

Comment: @JBNizet I don't think we can tell without more information whether `vote` should be a field or not.  If this is in a method that could be called reentrantly from different threads, then making it a field would be bad.  In any case, if this really is a variable used only inside the method, making it a field that could be accessed by other methods seems like a "design smell" to me.  (You did mean a field in the outer class, right?)

Comment: No, I did mean a field, whatever the class/object is. It could be the outer object, or a field of a "holder" object or a field of the listener.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The final local variable cannot be assigned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166521/the-final-local-variable-cannot-be-assigned)

Answer (score 28):

Well,  the standard trick is to use an int array of length one. Make the var final and write to `var[0]`. It is very important to make sure you don't create a data race. Using your code as an example:

```
final int[] vote = {0};

class SliderMoved implements ChangeListener {
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    vote[0] = ratingS.getValue();
  }
}
```

Since all this will be happenenig on the EDT, including the callback invocation, you should be safe. You should also consider using the anonymous class:

```
ratingS.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) { vote[0] = ratingS.getValue(); }
});
```

Comment: Can you show me the code in my case? How should i use this trick?

Comment: Why do you find it strange? You can't make the contents of the array final.

Comment: I find it strange because the error disappear just declaring it as array. I do not understand the why, anyway i don't care, i just solve my problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think you *should* always understand why something either works or not. In this case you can refer only to `final` vars from within a local class, but then you can't change them. However, you *can* change the contents of an array regardless of whether the variable pointing to the array is final or not.

Answer (score 5):

Move `vote` to `SliderMoved`:

```
class SliderMoved implements ChangeListener {
    private int vote;
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        this.vote = ratingS.getValue();
        // do something with the vote, you can even access
        // methods and fields of the outer class
    }
    public int getVote() {
        return this.vote;
    }
}

SliderMoved sm = new SliderMoved();
ratingS.addChangeListener(sm);

// if you need access to the actual rating...
int value = rattingS.getValue();

// ...or
int value2 = sm.getVote();
```

**EDIT**

Or alternatively, pass a model class to the change listener

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int vote;
    public int getVote() {
        return this.vote;
    }
    public void setVote(int vote) {
        this.vote = vote;
    }
    // omitting other setter and getter
}
```

`Person` is used as follows:

```
 class SliderMoved implements ChangeListener {
    private Person person;
    public SliderMoved(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        this.person.setVote(ratingS.getValue());
    }
    public Person getPerson() {
        return this.person;
    }
}

Person person = new Person();

ratingS.addChangeListener(new SliderMoved(person));

// access the vote
int vote = person.getVote();
```

Comment: **int value = ratingS.getValue();** can't work outside because that method is of the inner classe.
**int value2 = sm.getVote();** don't give me the actual rating, just the first change

Comment: `vote` is updated every time the state is changed and therefore `sm.getVote()` always should return the actual value. I prefer to do the whole work in `stateChanged(ChangeEvent)` and personally, I would remove `sm.getVote()`, but this depends on your needs.

Comment: You could actually use the model technique without having to pass it to the change listener, using a "holder" type design pattern. For example, outside of the change listener, you could declare:

`final Person person = new Person();`

and then in the change listener you can access/change the contents of the final `person` variable as long as you don't try and reassign the person itself:

`person.setVote(ratingS.getValue());`

IMHO, this is slightly more objecty that the array technique above :)

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved declaring vote as instance variable (private) in the main class.

Comment: If the main class is used more then once, every instance of the main class refers to the same instance variable. And this is very, very bad.

Comment: Do not worry, it is used just one time. Thank you for your comment

Comment: As I said, this is a very, very bad style. If you really must, make it a singleton as you never know who will use your class.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the Compiler compliance level to 1.8 worked for me to solve a similar problem. I don't understand the reason but you may try this.

How it works:

Right click on the project --> Properties --> Java Compiler. And in java compiler properties window, set the compiler compliance level to 1.8.

Comment: That is because in Java 1.8 the concept of effectively final variable is introduced. If the inner access is only a read access it works in 1.8. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4