# Java8 - "effectively final"

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, rx-java

I'm using RxVertx which is a sort of RxJava along with Java8 and I have a compilation error.

Here is my code:

```
public rx.Observable<Game> findGame(long templateId, GameModelType game_model, GameStateType state) {

return context.findGame(templateId, state)
    .flatMap(new Func1<RxMessage<byte[]>, rx.Observable<Game>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<Game> call(RxMessage<byte[]> gameRawReply) {

            Game game = null;

            switch(game_model) {

                case SINGLE: {

                    ebs.subscribe(new Action1<RxMessage<byte[]>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void call(RxMessage<byte[]> t1) {

                            if(!singleGame.contains(0) {
                                game = new Game();       // ERROR is at this line
                                singleGames.put(0, game);
                            } else {
                              game = singleGames.get(0); // ERROR is at this line
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            return rx.Observable.from(game);
        }
    });
}
```

The compilation error is:
"Local variable game defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

I cannot define 'game' as final since I do allocation\set and return it at the end of the function.

How can I make this code compile??

Thanks.

Comment: is the `public void call` executed right away? I'm not sure this code does what you think it does

Comment: possible duplicate of [The final local variable cannot be assigned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166521/the-final-local-variable-cannot-be-assigned)

Comment: Sebas: you maybe right, I'm brand new to RxJava and I found it hard to understand. but I mainly trying to solve one problem at a time :-)

Comment: Are you sure that `game = singleGames.get(0)` executes before `rx.Observable.from(game)`. Looks like this is not true.

Comment: talex: As I wrote Sebas, I'm not sure about the logic\flow of this method, all I'm interested at this point is solve the compilation error.

Comment: There is no need for this `contains`, `put`-or-`get` sequence. Learn about [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). A simple `game = singleGames.computeIfAbsent(0, k->new Game());` will do (and, as a bonus, be thread-safe, if the `singleGames` map is thread-safe).

Comment: You could use `AtomicReference`, though this usage is suspect in this context as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a `Holder` class that I use for situations like this.

```
/**
 * Make a final one of these to hold non-final things in.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class Holder<T> {
  private T held = null;

  public Holder() {
  }

  public Holder(T it) {
    held = it;
  }

  public void hold(T it) {
    held = it;
  }

  public T held() {
    return held;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return held == null;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(held);
  }

}
```

You can then do stuff like:

```
final Holder<Game> theGame = new Holder<>();
...

theGame.hold(myGame);
...
{
  // Access the game through the `final Holder`
  theGame.held() ....
```

Comment: Nice clean simple wrapper.

Comment: Ok, after looking better into your solution - I've chosen it becuase it's cleaner and more robust.

Thank you!

Comment: for the `toString` method you could actually do `String.valueOf(held)` which will return "null" if the string is null or call `held.toString()` in case it's not.

Comment: @foobar - Good call - fixed! Thanks.

Comment: You could use AtomicReference instead.

Comment: @stuartmarks - Indeed you could but that'd cause unnecessary memory barriers.

Comment: The memory barriers are necessary if the action is run on a different thread from the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to not modify the reference of the object you can wrap the `Game` in something else.

The quickest (but ugly) fix is to use an array of size 1, then set the content of the array later.  This works because the the array is effectively final, what is contained in the array doesn't have to be.

```
@Override
    public Observable<Game> call(RxMessage<byte[]> gameRawReply) {

        Game[] game = new Game[1];

        switch(game_model) {

            case SINGLE: {

                ebs.subscribe(new Action1<RxMessage<byte[]>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(RxMessage<byte[]> t1) {

                        if(!singleGame.contains(0) {
                            game[0] = new Game();       
                            singleGames.put(0, game[0]);
                        } else {
                          game[0] = singleGames.get(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        return rx.Observable.from(game[0]);
    }
```

Another similar option is to make a new class that has a `Game` field and you then set that field later.

Comment: As you said: "it's ugly" - but till I have better solution I go with it!
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Cyclops](https://github.com/aol/cyclops) has  [Mutable](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-base/4.0.2), and [LazyImmutable](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-base/4.0.2) objects for handling this use case. Mutable is fully mutable, and LazyImmutable is set once.

```
 Mutable<Game> game = Mutable.of(null);

 public void call(RxMessage<byte[]> t1) {

                        if(!singleGame.contains(0) {
                           game.mutate(g -> new Game());       
                            singleGames.put(0, game.get());
                        } else {
                          game[0] = game.mutate(g->singleGames.get(0));
                        }
               }
```

LazyImmutable can be used to set a value, lazily, once :

```
LazyImmutable<Game> game = LazyImmutable.def();

public void call(RxMessage<byte[]> t1) {

     //new Game() is only ever called once
     Game g = game.computeIfAbsent(()->new Game());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant. At least not directly. U can use a wrapper class however: just define a class "GameContainer" with game as its property and foward a final reference to this container instead.

Comment: I will do what dkatzel has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

@dkatzel's suggestion is a good one, but there's another option: extract everything about retrieving/creating the Game into a helper method, and then declare `final Game game = getOrCreateGame();`.  I think that's cleaner than the final array approach, though the final array approach will certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other approaches look acceptable, I'd like to mention that you can't be sure subscribing to `ebs` will be synchronous and you may end up always returning null from the inner function. Since you depend on another Observable, you could just simply compose it through:

```
public rx.Observable<Game> findGame(
        long templateId, 
        GameModelType game_model, 
        GameStateType state) {

    return context.findGame(templateId, state)
    .flatMap(gameRawReply -> {
        switch(game_model) {
        case SINGLE: {
            return ebs.map(t1 -> {
                Game game;
                if (!singleGame.contains(0) {
                    game = new Game();
                    singleGames.put(0, game);
                } else {
                    game = singleGames.get(0);
                }
                return game;
            });
        }
        }

        return rx.Observable.just(null);
    });
}
```