# The final local variable checkstate cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Tags: java, android

I have a class like this:

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity
{
CountDownTimer cntTimer = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timers);

    final ImageButton startTimerButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.timer1ImageButton);

    final EditText timerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timerEditText1);

    final TextView timerTextValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

    boolean checkstate =false;

    timerCountDown(checkstate,startTimer3Button,timerText3, timerTextValue3);
}

public void timerCountDown(boolean check,final ImageButton startTimerImageButton ,
        final EditText timerText,final TextView timerTextValue)
{
    Integer input = 0;
    if(timerText.getText().toString()!="")
        {
             input = Integer.parseInt(timerText.getText().toString())*1000 ;
        }

    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(input, 1000)
    {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
         {
             timerTextValue.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() 
         {
             timerTextValue.setText("done!");

         }
    };

    timerStatus(check,startTimerImageButton,timer);
}

public void timerStatus(final boolean checkstate, final ImageButton startTimer3Button ,final CountDownTimer downTimer) 
{
    startTimer3Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
                if(checkstate==false)
            {
                startTimer3Button.setImageResource(R.drawable.reset);
                //Error
                checkstate = true;
                downTimer.start();
            }
            else
            {
                startTimer3Button.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
                //Error
                checkstate = false;
                downTimer.cancel();
            }
         }
        });
}

}
```

but I get this error on the timerStatue method for checkstate = false and checkstate = true:
 The final local variable checkstate cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type!

I searched google and stackoverflow but did not find compatible answer for my problem!
Can you help me?
thanks in advance!

Comment: *None* of the related answers (listed to the right) gave you _any_ insight to the problem?

Comment: are you sure this is your final version of code? specially the part `timerStatus(boolean checkstate` because i think it should be `timerStatus(final boolean checkstate` and thats what caused the error, you can't re-assign final variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The final local variable cannot be assigned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166521/the-final-local-variable-cannot-be-assigned)

Comment: @WilliamPrice i followed that question but not solved my problem. :(

Comment: @Yazan i fixed that error! but checkstate = false and checkstate =true get me same error.

Comment: @AmirhosseinParsaeeyan you can not re-assign final variables, period.

Comment: @Yazan if i don't use of final i haven't access to onClick method and if i use final i can't re-assign that! so what should i do? :(

Comment: @AmirhosseinParsaeeyan now you have realized `whats going on?` check my answer below .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know want you meant to do with your code. It's a little fuzzy. As the Yazan said it's better to implement `OnClickListener` interface to avoid sending final to it's method.
After that why everything is `final`? You must define your variables in class level (class variables) to access them from other methods easily and the `onCreate()` method set their primary values.
So whatever I fixed your code like below without any error but I still didn't what It meant to do :

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity
{
    CountDownTimer cntTimer = null;
    ImageButton startTimerButton;
    EditText timerText;
    TextView timerTextValue;
    boolean checkstate =false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timers);

        startTimerButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.timer1ImageButton);

        timerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timerEditText1);

        timerTextValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

        timerCountDown();
    }

    public void timerCountDown()
    {
        Integer input = 0;
        if(timerText.getText().toString()!="")
            {
                 input = Integer.parseInt(timerText.getText().toString())*1000 ;
            }

        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(input, 1000)
        {
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
             {
                 timerTextValue.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

             public void onFinish() 
             {
                 timerTextValue.setText("done!");

             }
        };

        timerStatus(timer);
    }

    public void timerStatus(final CountDownTimer downTimer) 
    {
        startTimerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                    if(checkstate==false)
                {
                    startTimerButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_secure);
                    //Error
                    checkstate = true;
                    downTimer.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    startTimerButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
                    //Error
                    checkstate = false;
                    downTimer.cancel();
                }
             }
            });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a class that implements `OnClickListener` or even your current class can do that, and override `onclick()` in that way you can access any variable (not only final)

example: **Edit**

1) make you activity implements OnClickListener

2) override the method onClick() in your activity.

3) move `boolean checkstate =false;` at class level (outside of `onCreate()`)

4) change `startTimer3Button.setOnClickListener(...` to `startTimer3Button.setOnClickListener(TimerActivity.this);`

6) move the code inside onClick() that exist in timerStatus() to the onclick() added to the activity class

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


//code and methods ....

public void timerStatus(final boolean checkstate, final ImageButton startTimer3Button ,final CountDownTimer downTimer) 
{
    startTimer3Button.setOnClickListener(TimerActivity.this);
}

//code and methods ....
    @override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(checkstate==false)
        {
            startTimer3Button.setImageResource(R.drawable.reset);
            //Error
            checkstate = true;
            downTimer.start();
        }
        else
        {
            startTimer3Button.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
            //Error
            checkstate = false;
            downTimer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmirhosseinParsaeeyan i have edited the question, this should fix your issue, otherwise, if you could not manage to solve that, you need to read about many things, so you can handle your code.

Comment: if you got any errors for onClick() says variable not found, just declare that variable at class level (out of the methods, just like `CountDownTimer cntTimer = null;`)